# Weird Issue in Excel When Saved as ==> Csv

Tags: c#, office-interop

I have an excel file which contains some data when I save that file to CSV then some weird ? marks appear before & end of the text. Will any 1 please tell me how can I resolve that issue.

?XXXXXX-XXX?

Above is the link to download excel file : http://www.filedropper.com/book1_5

Comment: First, if you can paste some lines from the CSV, not many people would download a file (including myself). Regarding your error; could it be an encoding issue? Some characters are lost when exporting and a question mark replaces them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this file, in the column C you've got following data:

```
 "‭0000468750-IN‬"
 "‭0000468750-IN‬"
 "‭0000843576AB‬"
 "‭0000843576AB‬"
```

It is not reslly visible now, but at start and end of every number you have there an additional invisible whitespace character. You may see it for yourself, just edit that cell and move through the text by directional arrows - it will make a little pause when moving over that invisible character. If I replace it with an underscore, it looks like that:

```
 "_0000468750-IN_"
 "_0000468750-IN_"
 "_0000843576AB_"
 "_0000843576AB_"
```

If my text editor doesn't cheat on me, that character has code 0x00, and it's called null-character.

When converting to CSV, Excel didn't know what to do with that character. CSV is a textfile and must follow some encoding rules. For example, if you saved it as CSV/ANSI, then it's not possible to store some Unicode characters like `ąęćżń`. Similarly, it's usually not possible to store a 0x00 character in a textfile at all, because this character is special in most encodings. With this character inside, such textfile could be detected as "binary file" by readers and rejected.

Excel simply replaced that odd charcter with "?" character to make the data safe for CSV format. Excel didn't just erase the 0x00 character to let you know that there was something odd in the original data.

It's very strange to see it in textual data. If this XLSX was generated by a computer program, it might indicate that this program has some bugs/errors. I highly doubt this file to be manually created. It's really hard to write "0x00" character by hand. One option I can think of when you could get this manually is by using a crappy barcode reader, and scanning the codes right into the Excel sheet. The barcode scanning software sometimes leaks the control characters into the textdata stream. If that's the case, change the reader or write a filter that will cut those chars out.

Btw. you should be able to just find&replace all that strange characters. Edit one of the cells (F2 key), go to the end of the text (END key) select the LAST character of the text (Shift + LeftArrow ONCE), copy that character (Control + C), then open Find&Replace window (Control + H) and paster that character into "Find" and press "Replace All".

On my Excel this resulted in finding/replacing 8 such characters, so it works.

Note that after the END key you must press ShiftLeft exactly ONCE. The cursor will not move and nothing will happen, no selection will show up. That's because the character is invisible. But it is there, and it will be selected and copied.